# Can Any one help me on how to load a XML on the client side which is up on the sever and I need to make changes on the file

Tags: javascript

More over i need to make changes on that file and save it back on the server. I have to use javascript in order to do this?

Answer (score 0):

w3schools has a good tutorial for this: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

Specifically this might be what you are looking for to get started:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the help.!  But how do I modify the contents of the XML and save the updated file on the DB.?

Comment: The w3schools tutorial should have examples for modifying the XML. Then you'll need to post the altered XML back to the server, and then the server will need to save the changes to the file. There are lots of ways to do both of these. Maybe the best place to start would be any tutorial for whatever server side technology you are using.